# Putting each text file line in quotation marks using a .bat

Tags: batch-file, text

I have a text file and i need to put quotation marks at the start and end of every line using a .bat.
so:

first line:     `hello`
Second line:   `friends all`
thirst line:    `help`

please make it

first line     "hello"
second line    "friends all"
third line     "help"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

set "file_name=c:\file.txt"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%file_name%") do (

    (echo("%%#")

) >> temp.file

move /y temp.file "%file_name%"
```

to process a text file use [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) command

Comment: Please provide at least minimal explanation

Comment: Thank youuu! works perfect!!! I'm a newbie but I'm trying! haha thanks for your help

Comment: @ben you can accept the answer and give me some precious points :-)

Comment: If your question has been answered, please [mark the answer that you feel best addressed your question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), rather than posting a comment thanking the answerer. Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the accepted answer and any other answers you found useful.